# Place widgets into Frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying out something new on Tkinter (I am still a newbie), but it keeps failing...maybe someone could help out?

I wanted to create a window with several Frames, so that I can open and close them and show that way different content. However I am already stuck with not being able to "place" the, in this case a button, to the frame. Instead I get a blank frame with nothing inside...

The reason I want to use the place manager is so that I can easily choose the x and y coordinates.  I don't want to create empty columns just in order to get a button appear in the middle of the screen.

Here the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter window")
root.geometry("800x600")

StartFrame = Frame(root)
StartFrame.pack()

Button1 = Button(StartFrame, command = StartTkinter, text = "Start", bg = "white", fg = "black", height = 2, width = 15)
Button1.place(x=0, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to specify the dimensions of the frame.  So, by default, it is created to be just 1 pixel high and 1 pixel wide.  This means that its contents will not be visible on the window.

To fix the problem, you can either set exact values for these dimensions when you create the frame:

```
StartFrame = Frame(root, height=600, width=800)
```

or you can do:

```
StartFrame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
```

to have the frame fill all available space.

Comment: The default dimension is 1x1, not 0x0, though for all intents and purposes those two are identical.